# Why does Google Wallet depend not only on the Phone but the Carrier as well?

Tags: t-mobile, google-wallet, moto-x

I'm trying to use Google Wallet on a Moto X at Duane Reed.  I'm under the impression that this *should* work.

However, when I browsed the help file for Wallet, it lists a number of Moto-X compatible devices, but they also list the cellular service.

- What is the technological, or vendor relationship that is needed in order to Google wallet work with Moto-X with T-Mobile?
- Why is there a dependency outside of the actual phone?  Is the cellular operator working with Google, sharing my PII, and monitoring my transactions?

My goal is to understand the extent the cellular operator is monitoring my on-device actions, and purchases.

Comment: It's probably just a business thing, but really, in order to get a definitive answer you'd probably have to ask the carriers/Google why it is the way it is. As an example, though, Verizon has it's own mobile payment platform, [Isis](http://www.verizonwireless.com/b2c/explore/?page=isis). Google Wallet is a competitor, and historically they have not supported it.

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Wallet Privacy Policy](http://wallet.google.com/files/privacy.html) specifies that personally identifiable information and transaction data are only shared with the carrier if necessary to allow *carrier billing* (that is, where purchases made via Google Wallet appear on and are paid through your phone bill).

The relationship between Google and the carriers for this purpose is a purely business one. The only involvement of the carrier in the transaction is (a) if carrier billing is involved, as I said above, or (b) if you use 3G to make a payment over Internet, instead of through NFC. As eldarerathis says, several carriers have payment services that compete with Google Wallet, and Google can't afford to fall out with carriers.

If you're worried about privacy from your cellular operator, please do remember that they have the ability to "customize" your ROM, if you buy your phone through them. Software that monitors your on-device actions and purchases might *already* be installed on your phone, before you even start using Google Wallet

Answer (score 0):

With the 4.4 KitKat update, the Moto X (and any other device with NFC running 4.4) can use Google Wallet regardless of carrier, as stated [here](https://support.google.com/wallet/answer/1347934?hl=en). You can also check out the screengrab below:

[image]